# Drupal module development, custom database tables, pages for managing those data

Tags: module, drupal-7

I'm completely new to Drupal development
I want to learn how to create basic module with such functionality:

Create module with custom database tables
Create one or several new pages as logical section of the site
Manage data from database tables on those newly created pages

For example, I want to create subscription service with clients database
and manage their data (edit clients, export, change their status, etc...)

I want to do this on new pages on my site (not in admin section)
site.com/clients - list of client
site.com/client - client detailed info 
etc

Please, provide some thoughts or tutorials (but not a ready module :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial for the basics in creating a D7 module.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360

As far as custom database tables I suggest taking a look at this module.
https://www.drupal.org/project/eck

Also take a look at this video for more info about 'ECK'.
http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-entity-construction-kit